# Custom javascript not working in Wordpress AMP

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

I am using most of the plugins in WordPress for AMP, but it does not allow custom javascript in AMP.

Is there any way for that?

Please help me if anyone faces that kind of issue.

Thanks

Comment: It's difficult to know which plugin the error is coming from. Here's a link to similar issues: [link]https://wordpress.org/support/topic/amp-critical-error-custom-javascript-is-not-allowed/

Answer (score 1):

Author written JavaScript is not allowed via the AMP specification. You'll need to execute your JavaScript with an [amp-iframe](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-iframe) instead.

From the ["How AMP Works" page](https://www.ampproject.org/learn/about-how/):

> AMP pages can’t include any author-written JavaScript. Instead of
>   using JavaScript, interactive page features are handled in custom AMP
>   elements. The custom AMP elements may have JavaScript under the hood,
>   but they’re carefully designed to make sure they don’t cause
>   performance degradation.